# Socket refresh python

Tags: python, sockets, select

I coded a basic socket system with "select". I want get the list of connected clients instantly.

When the timeout of "select" has passed and several clients come after, it's the drama..

Example - Concerns: 
I have 3 clients with one that connects before the timeout, 2 others are connected after the timeout, so I'm going to refresh my list if it took into account two other clients after the timeout.

1st result: I display my variable "list", I see the first socket that is connected before the timeout + one of the other socket who is connected after the timeout. Total: 2 of 3 clients

2nd result: I still re-display my variable "list", and the three clients are there ....

But I want the list without having to re-display the list every time for every customer you can imagine I have 10 clients and I have to show my liste10 times

So I thought to use the asyncore module who is more fluid, what do you think? Do you have a solution for me (easier)? Should I use the multi-threading or stayed on asyncore or select module?

EDIT CODE SOURCE:

```
import socket, select

hote = ''
port = 81

mainConnection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mainConnection.bind((hote, port))
mainConnection.listen(5)
print("Listen to {}".format(port))

client_online = []

while True:

    connection_access, wlist, xlist = select.select([mainConnection], [], [], 10)

    for connexion in connection_access:
        connection_client, infos_connexion = connexion.accept()
        client_online.append(connection_client)



    refresh = input(">>> ")

    while True:
        try:
            refresh = int(refresh)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not allowed")
            refresh = int(refresh)
        else:
            break

    if refresh == 1:
        print("List client : {}".format(client_online))
```

Comment: `select` should return when at least one of the sockets in the sets are ready.

Comment: no :/ i must return the list 2 times for show 3 clients ...

Comment: Please show the code you use, or at least an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I make a video with a problem [video here](http://p13.shpv.fr/prob.avi)

Comment: The formatting of the code is a little off, but it seems to me that you have an infinite loop where you call `select` *only* on the main listening socket, possibly only once (since the formatting is off, remember that indentation is important in Python). You do not check any other connected socket, and neither do you ever attempt to receive or send any data from or to the connected sockets.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry the indentation in the post is bad x) I corrected , I forgot to indent my code in the editor stackoverflow (in IDLE python it was well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three major problems with your code:

1. You call `input` in your loop. This function will *block* until <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed.
2. If a non-integer is input from the console, you will get an exception. You handle that exception, but you handle it wrongly. Instead or asking for input again, you simply try to perform the same operation that caused the exception again.
3. You only check for incoming connection in your `select` call. You never check if any of the connected sockets have sent anything.

The major problem here for you is the call to `input` as it will completely stop your program until input from the console is entered.

Comment: Ok Thank's !! So, how i can do for call an input ?

Comment: @Wiz Add [`sys.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) to the read-set of `select`. When it's readable you can call e.g. [`sys.stdin.read`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) to get input.

Comment: Okok but i want just write not read (just for show list) I don't want use recv()

Answer (score 0):

Your post is very unclear but I can tell you that the problem is that you aren't understanding how to use `select`.

The code you posted only calls select one time. The program gets to the `select()` call and waits for `mainConnection` to be readable (or for the timeout). If `mainConnection` becomes readable before the timeout, `select()` returns with one readable file descriptor which you then process in your `for` loop. But that's it. `select` is never called again and so your program never checks for any more incoming connections.

In almost every application `select` should be in a loop. Each time through the loop the program waits in the `select()` call until one or more sockets is ready for reading or writing. When that happens, `select` gives you the file descriptors that are ready and it's your job to have other code actually do something. For example, if `select` returns a socket's file descriptor as readable it's your job to call `.recv()` on that socket.

You can certainly use asyncore. In fact, I think you should study the source code for asyncore to learn how to properly use `select`.

Comment: Yes, the `select` function in Python knows how to handle socket objects correctly.

Comment: Ok, removed that part of the post. Thanks.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry the indentation in the post is bad x) I corrected , I forgot to indent my code in the editor stackoverflow (in IDLE python it was well)